# grep behaving abnormally

Tags: grep

`grep` is behaving different when letter `a` is being searched. when letter `a` is included in search criteria, it is not searching for any other letter. But it is not the same case with other characters. Why?!

For command : `grep [aeiou] file1` or `grep [eioau] file1` or `grep [a,e,i,o,u] file1` , it is showing following output:

```
Name : file1 
a
```

> **Note1**: letter 'a' is being highlighted as searched character in output(screenshot attached).

And for command : `grep [eiou] file1` or `grep [e,i,o,u] file1` , it is showing following output:

```
this is test file.
Name : file1
```

> **Note2**: letters 'e' & 'i' are being highlighted as searched characters in output(screenshot attached).

**file1** is:

```
this is test file.
Name : file1
a
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Always put arguments / parameters containing shell met characters such as `[` and `]` in quotes, i.e. `grep '[aeiou]' file1`

Comment: I think it is better to put the terminal stuff in plain text (or formatted as code) instead of an screenshot. In the mobile version of U&L it is not easy to see it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a file called `a` in your current directory. you haven't quoted the RE passed to `grep`, so this is what is happening:

Given

```
grep [aeiou] file1
```

The shell sees `[aeiou]` and because it's a valid (glob) pattern it tries to match that against a single letter file `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`. Since it succeeds it replaces the parameter with the file it matched, `a`. The entire result is then executed as a command:

```
grep a file1
```

And this gives you the output you are seeing. I should point out that if the shell cannot glob your pattern it leaves it unchanged. This allows `[eiou]` to succeed where apparently `[aeiou]` "fails".

The solution is to single-quote your non-file parameters, like this:

```
grep '[aeiou]' file1
```

Comment: Resolved. Thanks. I'm beginning with unix so please pardon if it's too silly!

Comment: Note that there's no harm in quoting other arguments either like `'grep' '[aeiou]' 'file1'`. However, it's not needed. Only characters special in the shell syntax (or for the first argument, reserved names like `while`, `do`...) need quoted to remove their special meaning. Note that, in Bourne like shells, `[` is not special when by itself in an argument. That's why you can get away with `[ -f file ]` and don't need to write it `'[' -f file ']'`

Comment: @Sachin I doubt there are many questions that are "too silly" as long as the person asking them has done appropriate research for their level. Your question was clear and to the point.

Comment: The part about the shell leaving the pattern unchanged when there are no matches depend on shell and configuration. For example in bash you can type `shopt -s failglob` or add it to your `.bashrc` in order to have bash fail rather than leaving the pattern unchanged. Getting an error in those cases can help spot the root cause of such problems much sooner.